# Given y=atan(x)/x, how can I get "x" for a given value of "y"?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a simple C++ equation that I'm using to perform lens distortion correction.

$$y=\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}$$

where $x$ is in radians between 0.0 and 1.0.

I'm trying to come up with the inverse of this equation [get $x$ given $y$] but I've been unsuccessful. I got this far before my flabby math skills were exhausted:

$$xy = \arctan(x)$$
$$\tan(xy) = x.$$

I realize that this question sounds like a homework problem but trust me, I haven't had homework in several decades. I would appreciate pointers on where to look or even google terms.

Comment: I think you need to solve it numerically, e.g., relaxation, bisection, Newton's method, etc.

Comment: Equation is of transcendental character. Can't be solved in a closed form.

Comment: As Kyson said, numerical methods ! If you need, I could provide rather good estimates for $0<x<1$. Newton method should be very simple to implement.

Comment: You can rearrange into $\frac{\tan(w)}w=\frac 1y,w=xy$. This site has approximations/expressions for the multi-branch inverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments and answers, there is no closed form of the solution and numerical methods need to be used.

Admitting you know Newton method, the problem is to start with a reasonable estimate of the solution. The nice thing is that using Pade approximants, we have $$y=\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x} \approx \frac{1+\frac{4 x^2}{15}}{1+\frac{3 x^2}{5}}$$ So, for a given $y$, solving the quadratic gives $$x_0=\sqrt{\frac{15 (1-y)}{9 y-4}}$$ Now, you can safely start Newton.

**Edit**

The formula can be improved assuming $$y=\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x} \approx \frac{1+ax^2 }{1+bx^2}$$ and setting $b=\frac{4 (a+1)}{\pi }-1$ in order to exactly match the value of $y$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$. Minimizing $$F(a)=\int_0^1 \Big(\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x}- \frac{1+ax^2 }{1+bx^2}\Big)^2\,dx$$ lead to $a=0.217886$ and accordingly $b=0.550661$ . This leads to  $$x_0=\sqrt{\frac {1 - y}{0.550661 y-0.217886}}$$

**Edit**

We can improve the approximation using an higher degree Pade approximant and get  $$y=\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x} \approx   \frac{\frac{64 x^4}{945}+\frac{7 x^2}{9}+1}{\frac{5 x^4}{21}+\frac{10 x^2}{9}+1}$$ and get $$x_0=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{35} \sqrt{800 y^2-1432 y+947}-350 y+245}{225
   y-64}}$$ For example $y=0.85$ will lead to $x_0=0.777582$ while the exact solution is $x=0.777478$ while the previous approximation lead to $x_0=0.774324$.

Using these estimates, one or two Newton iterations will be needed for six or more significant digits.

Comment: For $x=0.5$, $\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x}=0.927295$ and $\frac{1+\frac{4 x^2}{15}}{1+\frac{3 x^2}{5}}=0.927536$

Comment: At any time you can delete your own comment clicking on X button at right. Others cannot or should not do it for you.

Comment: Claude, your first reading was correct y=atan(x)/x. My mistakes in Excel led me to my (now deleted) comment. Thank you sooo much.

Comment: @ChrisBennet.You are very welcome ! Do you need more ?

Comment: @Claude, I'm trying it now in my code. I'll post back with status. :-)

Comment: @Claude: After further investigation in turned out that my lens correction formula was:
 y = x * arctan(x * k) / k
 which had a trivial inverse (x = tan(y*k)/k)
 Your help was not in vain however, you've revealed Pade' approximates to me for which I will be forever grateful.

Comment: Glad to discover Padé approximants : they are much more powerful than Taylor series. If your formula is $y=\frac xk\, \tan^{-1}(xk)$, the inverse you wrote is not correct.

Comment: I shall add a new answer for $y=\frac xk\, \tan^{-1}(xk)$

Comment: My comment had a mistake, the original formula should have been "y = arctan(x * k) / k" with the trivial inverse "x = tan(y * k) / k". Sorry for causing you more work!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read x for given y, there are three ways.

First one is approximate, reading off from a graph.

Second use Newton-Raphson iteration procedure.

Third, set up a differential equation, change $ \frac {dy}{dx}\rightarrow \frac {-1}{dy/dx} $ and integrate to get x for uniform y increments.

Answer (score 0):

As said in a comment, the problem changed to $$y=\frac xk\, \tan^{-1}(xk)$$ Fos simplicity, let us define $t=kx$ and $z=k^2y$ to make $$z=t \, \tan^{-1}(t)$$ If we look at the graph of the function, there are clearly two different behaviors.

When $t$ is small (say $0 \leq z \leq 1$), $t \, \tan^{-1}(t)$ can be approximated either by a Taylor series which makes $$z \approx t^2-\frac{t^4}{3}$$ which leads to the approximation $$t\approx\frac{\sqrt{3-\sqrt{3} \sqrt{3-4 z}}}{\sqrt{2}}$$ or by a Pade approximant $$z \approx \frac{t^2}{\frac{t^2}{3}+1}$$ which leads to the approximation $$t\approx\frac{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{3-z}}$$

Let us try with $z=\frac 12$; the Taylor based approximation gives $t_0=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{3}\right)}\approx 0.796225$; Newton iterates xill then be : $0.765692$, $0.765379$ which is the solution for six significant figures. The Pade based approximation gives $t_0=\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\approx 0.774597$ from which the iterates are $0.765408$, $0.765379$.

More interesting is the case where $z$ is large; Taylor expansion gives $$z\approx \frac{\pi  t}{2}-1$$ which leads to the approximation $$t\approx \frac{2 (z+1)}{\pi }$$ Let us try with $z=10$; the Taylor based approximation gives $t_0=\frac{22}{\pi }\approx 7.00282$;  Newton iterates xill then be : $6.99854$ which is the solution for six significant figures.